# How to implement work stealing in SimPy 3?

Tags: simpy

I want to implement something akin to work stealing or task migration in multiprocessor systems. Details below.

I am simulating a scheduling system with multiple worker nodes (resources, each with multiple capacity), and tasks (process) that arrive randomly and are queued by the scheduler at a specific worker node. This is working fine.

However, I want to trigger an event when a worker node has spare capacity, so that it steals the front task from the worker with the longest wait queue.

I can implement the functionality described above. The problem is that all the tasks waiting on the worker queue from which we are stealing work receive the event notification. I want to notify ONLY the task at the front of the queue (or only N tasks at the front of the queue).

The Bank reneging example is the closest example to what I want to implement. However, it (1) ALL the customers leave the queue when they are notified that the event was triggered, and (2) when event is triggered, the customers leave the system; in my example, I want to make the task wait at another worker (though it wouldn't wait, since the queue of that worker is empty).

Old question: Can this be done in SimPy?

New questions: How can I do this in SimPy?
1) How can I have many processes, waiting for a resource, listen for an event, but notify only the first one?
2) How can I make a process migrate to another resource?